# How to Identify and Delete duplicate vertices?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, geometry, topology, vertices, data-reviewer

I am trying to figure out how to delete duplicate vertices.  I have successfully determined that there are [duplicate vertices using PLTS Data Reviewer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Finding_duplicate_vertices/01020000000r000000/), but I am confounded as to how I identify and remove individual vertices.  I have tried [repair geometry](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003v000000) to no avail, and I was wondering if anyone had some advice.  I am working in a file geodatabase in ArcMap 10.0 with Data Reviewer extension.

Comment: Simplify Line (Cartography) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//007000000010000000 will remove them.

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz, I had considered this approach.  However, It would create more work than I would like to create new geometry.  I would like to work with existing geometry if possible.

Comment: @Barbarossa Have you tried Check Geometry (Data Management)? it can identify Duplicate vertices.

Comment: @Arash, I have tried both Check Geometry and Repair Geometry.  Neither tell me that I have duplicate vertices, but Data Reviewer tells me different.

Comment: Could you tell me how you did this "I buffered this point error feature class by 0.5m and erased the buffer geometry from my original. "?? Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to the current question. If you have a question of your own, please use the Ask Question button on top.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because *Check Geometry* and *Data Reviewer* seem to be contradictory in your case, I suggest to use **[Feature Vertices To Points](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003p000000)** and then **[Collect Events](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005p0000003s000000)**. The events with `ICOUNT > 1` are the duplicate vertices you are looking for.

In order to delete duplicate vertices from the original geometries, for instance I'd use **GDAL/OGR** (>= 1.10 with SpatiaLite support):

```
ogr2ogr clean_polygons.shp dirty_polygons.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Buffer(geometry,0), * FROM dirty_polygons"
```

Comment: Could you add some more details on this answer?  Does this require the usage of `sqlite` to store the shape data?  Could you provide an answer if I have an existing `.shp` file that I simply want to 'clean'?

Answer (score 3):

This is a two tool process using [ET GeoWizard](http://www.ian-ko.com/) toolbar within ArcMap:

First make sure each polygon feature has a unique id value.

1. Use [Polygon to Point](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/ToolBox/toolbox_userguide.htm) tool and define 'vertices' and 'remove duplicate points' options
2. Use [Points to Polygon](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/ToolBox/toolbox_userguide.htm) tool and define the id column as the 'polygon ID field'

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Mapperz' approach for something automated.

However, if you would like to get into the guts of the vertices, once you are editing, open up the "Sketch Properties" from the "Advanced Editing" toolbar.  You can also find it if you search for it in the Customize Mode and then add it to a toolbar of your choice.  It brings up a list of all your vertices.  As you select them in the "Sketch Properties" window, they will highlight in the map and you can choose to delete as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks @cndnflyr, But this approach would take considerable amounts of time as I have hundreds of polygons, each with thousands of vertices.  However, If I could identify the vertices in question, this could work.

Comment: How comfortable are you with Python?  You could look into the Geometry of each polygon and compare all the points that are in it.  What you do after that is up to you.  Either delete all but one, notify you, move it to a different location for you to run a different tool on it.  Sky's the limit.  Let me know if you would like further tips in that direction.

Comment: @cndcflyr, I have some python experience and have considered looking into it if something can be accomplished.  I have never read/modified feature geometry before.  Any tips are welcomed.

Comment: I played around with polygon geometries for awhile, but have had to stop before I get a working script.  Part of my problem was I couldn't create a feature in ArcMap with duplicate points.  Which is normally good I guess, but Arrgh!  I still think it would work, but, all the best! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Feature Vertices To Points (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003p000000) to convert all the vertices to point. Then using topology validation find the points that self intersect. See [ArcGIS: Working With 
Geodatabase Topology](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/whitepapers/ao_/geodatabase-topology.pdf) 
 for more information. This way you should be able to find the duplicate vertices but removing the extra vertices is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions guys.  I found a solution, albeit not exactly ideal for my situation.  PLTS Data Review creates a reviewer feature dataset within the GDB, which includes reviewer points, lines, and polygons.  The points represent point check errors (i.e. duplicate vertices).  These can be visualized using [PLTS table reviewer](http://esri.force.com/ideaView?id=087E00000004VSm&returnUrl=/apex/ideaList?c=09a300000004xET&category=ArcGIS%2bDesktop%2bExtensions).  I buffered this point error feature class by 0.5m and erased the buffer geometry from my original.  No more point errors.  I know this may not work for others' situations, but I am dealing with large polygons with thousands of vertices each.  One could buffer by whatever radius necessary to create valid geometry.  It would be nice to have python do this for me without drastically altering the geometry.  But this works for me for now.  Again, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

With ArcGIS You can create a .gdb. Inside it new 'Feature Dataset..' and setup XY tolerance (Points within that distance will be merged). Import your feature class and run "Check / Repair geometry" on it.